# Computerless, wireless web activated remote printing

Tags: asp.net, printing

Im in need of a solution, I basically require a way to print from a web page to a printer. But the printer needs to be standalone, either plugging directly into phone line, using a sim card etc. Does anyone know of a good solution for this?

It needs to be cheap to run, setup costs aren't that much of an issue, but obviously the cheaper the better.

Answer (score 0):

If landline is okay, I believe the device you want is an antiquated piece of hardware called a "fax machine"

If wireless on a mobile network, the service plan is more of a cost concern than the hardware, though the two might be bundled together.  For example, a company called bug labs is working on some kind of partnership with verizon for connecting their embedded linux device construction kit.